# how to test if stanfordnlp is running on gpu?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

How can I test whether [stanfordnlp](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/) is running on the gpu?

[Here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/) is some sample code:

```
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download('en')   # This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline() # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He was elected president in 2008.")
doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

I changed this slightly, to point to my model directory:

```
config = {'models_dir': '/scratch/lklein/models'}
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(**config)
```

My machine has CUDA and when I run the code, I get the following output:

```
Use device: gpu
---
Loading: tokenize
With settings: 
{'model_path': '/scratch/lklein/models/en_ewt_models/en_ewt_tokenizer.pt', 'lang': 'en', 'shorthand': 'en_ewt', 'mode': 'predict'}

...
```

So the setup is correct, it does detect the gpu.
How can I query this computationally? Ideally, I'm looking for something like spacy's [`require_gpu`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#spacy.require_gpu).

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `nvidia-smi` in bash while the code is executing.

That being said, the default behavior is to use a GPU when available 
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp/blob/d8061501ff14c73734e834a08fa33c58c4a6d917/stanfordnlp/pipeline/core.py#L102